# Email auto responder - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, email, frameworks, auto-responder

Ok I want to do this:

If an email comes in to info@woodviolins.com, it looks at the email's fields. For example:

```
Name:elijah wood
Address:77 apple avenue
```

And enters that data into an address book contact. Depending on the fields someone might have sent in a "price quote" or a "brochure request". Like this:

If this field is present in the email:

```
Model:(model name)
```

then the email is a "price quote". Otherwise, it's a brochure request. If it determined that the email coming in was a price quote, it will email the person back with one email. If it determined that the email coming in was a brochure request, it will email the person back with another email.

It will then sort the emails into folders: "pricequotes", "brochures", and  "errors". The errors folder is where a field doesn't have a value. For example:

```
Name:(blank)
```

Also, it will count the number of price quotes, brochure requests, and errors and put's them in a .txt file and sends that in the email to the moderator (look below).

2. At the end of the day (11:59 PM) it exports all the contacts it has created in address book, and exports them to .VCF.
3. Then sends the .VCF file to the moderator's email.
4. deletes the cards already in the address book to start over.

Now, I want this to all be in ONE objective-c mac application. What frameworks would I need to make this work? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Elijah

Comment: Are you using Mail.app? If so, this is pretty easily done using Applescript and a filter.

Comment: Well, I don't want to be. Yes, I already made an Applescript version, but it's in need of an upgrade, and I'm in need of a project! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSMail Framework?

http://www.coriolis-systems.com/opensource/